# jQuery unrecognized expression for some Chinese characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, unrecognized-selector

I have created some inputs dynamically.

But some Chinese characters cause unrecognized expression issue and some are working.

For e.g.,

I have two class that contains with some Chinese characters.

> 1) selected-item rate-type-成人(13岁以上) - Not Valid
>
> 2) selected-item rate-type-儿童（4_12岁） - Valid

Both are contains Chinese characters but first one cause unrecognized expression problem.

```js
try {
    var getValid   = $(".selected-item.rate-type-儿童（4_12岁）");
    document.write(getValid.data("text"));
    var getInvalid = $(".selected-item .rate-type-成人(13岁以上)");
    document.write(getValid.data("text"));
} catch(e) {
    document.write("<br />");
    document.write(e);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="selected-item rate-type-成人(13岁以上)" data-text="Not Valid Class">
  
</div>

<div class="selected-item rate-type-儿童（4_12岁）" data-text="Valid Class">
  
</div>
```

Have any idea how to resolve this ?

Thanks !

Comment: Only use Ascii in class names? And all spaces are ignored

Comment: Why do you need to use chinese in class names? I don't see that like a good practice.

Comment: @mplungjan there are no any whitespace.

Comment: @lepe because that is generated by user inputs. You are right but as per requirement I need to use that for identify `div`.

Comment: Actually I am stuck on some characters are working but some are not. Why ?

Comment: `jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .rate-type-成人(13岁以上)`

Comment: I closed with the wrong dupe. Just do not use special chars in selectors. You will have a headache escaping them. You need to escape the `(` and `)` in the first, the second set in double byte `（` and `）` is not recognised as a special char

Comment: @mplungjan you are right. Thank you so much !